# Override public virtual function with private base function?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, using-declaration, private-inheritance

Let's consider two classes `A` and `B` with the following interface:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void start() {} //default implementation does nothing
};

class B {
public:
    void start() {/*do some stuff*/}
};
```

and then a third class which inherits from both, `A` publicly because it implements this "interface", and `B` privately because that's implementation detail.

However, in this specific implementation, `start()` only has to contain a call to `B::start()`. So I thought I could use a shortcut and do the following:

```
class C: public A, private B {
public:
    using B::start;
};
```

and be done with it, but apparently it doesn't work. So I get `using` private base function doesn't work in order to override virtuals. From that, two questions:

- Is there any way to make this work as I supposed it may have worked?
- Why would the compiler accept this code as valid? As I see it there are now two `start()` functions with the exact same signature in `C` and yet the compiler seems fine with it and only calls `A::start()`.

EDIT: A few precisions:

- The goal is to manipulate `C` objects through `A` pointers.
- I'm currently using a simple function that just calls `B::start()`, I was specifically wondering if a using declaration could indeed "override" a virtual, and if not, how this was allowed to have both functions coexist.
- I might have omitted a few things like `virtual` inheritance for simplicity.

Comment: It is not clear what you're expecting. `C c; c.start();` should call `B::start()`.

Comment: It is working here: http://ideone.com/e71lnB

Comment: @Rama I guess it's more about A* a = &c; a->start(); for your ideone sample

Comment: @grek40 Thanks! got it!, Not working now... ideone.com/e71lnB

Comment: Are you looking for `void C::start() override { B::start(); }`?

Comment: @ZDF In short, yes I think.

Comment: I should have been more specific indeed. I manipulate a `C` through an `A*` indeed.

Comment: There is no using directive in your code.

Comment: @curiousguy Hmm, now that you say that, I might wrongly use the term indeed. Using directives are only for namespace stuff and what I should use is "using declarations". Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to make this work as I supposed it may have worked?

You should override the member function and explicitly call `B::start()`:

```
class C: public A, private B {
public:
    void start() override { B::start(); }
};
```

> Why would the compiler accept this code as valid? As I see it there
>   are now two `start()` functions with the exact same signature in C and
>   yet the compiler seems fine with it and only calls `A::start()`.

You are right, there are two member functions accessible in C (`A::start()` and `B::start()`). And in `class C`, without overriding `start()` or making the `start()` of any of the base classes visible by doing a `using ...::start()`, you will have ambiguity error when trying to call the member function using unqalified namelookup from an object of `C`.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void start() { std::cout << "From A\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    void start() { std::cout << "From B\n"; }
};

class C: public A, private B {
};

int main(){
    A* a = new C();
    a->start();       //Ok, calls A::start()

    C* c = new C();
    c->start();       //Error, ambiguous         
}
```

To fix that, you will have to use the qualified name such as:

```
    C* c = new C();
    c->A::start();       //Ok, calls A::start()
```

---

Now, doing a `using B::start()` in `class C` simply declares the `start()` to refer to `B::start()` whenever such name is used from an object of `C`

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void start() { std::cout << "From A\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    void start() { std::cout << "From B\n"; }
};

class C: public A, private B {
public:
     using B::start();
};

int main(){
    A* a = new C();
    a->start();       //Ok, calls A::start()

    C* c = new C();
    c->start();       //Ok, calls B::start()
}
```

`using B::start` makes the function `void B::start()` visible in `C`, it does not override it. To call make all the above unqualified member function call, to call `B::start()`, you should override the member function in `C`, and make it call `B::start()`

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void start() { std::cout << "From A\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    void start() { std::cout << "From B\n"; }
};

class C: public A, private B {
public:
    void start() override { B::start(); }
};

int main(){
    A* a = new C();
    a->start();         //Ok, calls C::start() which in turn calls B::start()
                        //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - by virtual dispatch

    C* c = new C();
    c->start();         //Ok, calls C::start() which in turn calls B::start()

}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm resorting to the solution you mentioned first, right now. I was wondering more specifically if there was a way to have the `using` directive "override" the virtual function.

Comment: @JBL, `using` doesn't affect vtables, it's mostly a compile-time mechanism in C++ for dealing with names, and cannot be used for overriding, overriding on the other hand has effects on the member function pointers in the class vtable

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. Thanks for your explanations!

Comment: I got same result when I don't use `overwrite` keyword:`void start() { B::start(); }`